How can I reuse an Angular subscribe function?
How can I reuse a subscribe function to update data, since I need to perform actions after the result of the call in another function? Do I need to do another subscribe? Naturally, I can't use async/await to make the process wait, I put the code like this because that's how it was with fetch before.
ngOnInit() {        
    this.carregaDados();
}

carregaDados() {

    this.dataService.getData().subscribe({
        next: (res:Result) => {
            
            if(!res.success) {
                this.errors.set([res.errors[0]?.message || "Erro desconhecido"]);                                   
            }
            else {
                this.conectar(this.dataService.data);
                this.dataFilters = this.dataService.geraObjFiltros();
                this.dateTimeUpdatelabel.set(this.dataService.dateTimeUpdateLabel)          
            }
            
        },
        error: (err) => {
            console.log('Erro:',err.message)
            this.errors.set([err.message]);             
        }
    });

}

async atualizarGrid() {
    
    const estadoGrid = this.datasource.estadoCorrente
    await this.carregaDados();
    const dataFiltered = this.dataService.goFilterFinal();
    this.conectar(dataFiltered);

    this.datasource.ordenacao = estadoGrid.ordenacao;
    this.datasource.tamanhoPagina = estadoGrid.tamanhoPagina;
    this.datasource.pagina = estadoGrid.pagina;
    
    console.log(this.datasource.estadoCorrente)     
}

atualizarGridAnotherSubscribe() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
        (result:Result) => {
            
            const estadoGrid = this.datasource.estadoCorrente
            const dataFiltered = this.dataService.goFilterFinal();
            this.conectar(dataFiltered);

            this.datasource.ordenacao = estadoGrid.ordenacao;
            this.datasource.tamanhoPagina = estadoGrid.tamanhoPagina;
            this.datasource.pagina = estadoGrid.pagina;

            this.dateTimeUpdatelabel.set(this.dataService.dateTimeUpdateLabel);

        }
    );
}

I subscribed again and repeated the information from the previous subscriber, but it doesn't seem like the best solution.

@YongShun yes, i update code with ngOnInit()

I saw you remove the arrow pointing to this.carregaDados() in the atualizarGrid method and add the atualizarGridAnotherSubscribe method which did the similar logic. So what I understand you want to revamp carregaDados so that it is reusable in both ngOnInit() and atualizarGrid()? Or can you specify what you try to achieve, pointing which part of code you want to be reused?

I would like to reuse the atualizarGrid(), but adding some actions that would be executed after its execution, so that I don't need to repeat the methods already used in carregaDados(). I created this other function atualizarGridAnotherSubscribe() to indicate that this way works perfectly, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach? If so, then for each new function I should call a new subscribe from the service? Is that it?

Really I don't understand so much the question, but...
When we want to execute some when subscribe we can use a subject, and the rxjs operators startsWith (execute indmediatmy) and switchMap (change one observable to another observable)
dispatcher$!:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>()

ngOnInit()
{
   this.dispatcher$.pipe(
     startsWith(null),
     switchMap(_=>this.mainObservable()
   )).subscribe((res:any)=>{
         ..here we have the response of "mainObservable"..
   })
}

In this way, in ngOnInit we execute the mainObservable and execute the actions and also we can do
   this.dispatcher$.next(null)

And execute again the "mainObservable"
a little stackblitz (In the example the "mainObservable" is a call to a service.getData())
